# jquery ui resizable() not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareksmakosz/GMgx8/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="empty ui-widget-content">
    <div class="settings-menu">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.empty {
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 6px 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
}
```

JS

```
$('.empty').resizable();
```

Why, oh why does so basic stuff happen?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GMgx8/4/ i add jquery.UI as external resourse and it works, maybe some problem with JsFiddle libraries

Comment: maybe you could report it to the fiddle team

Comment: the problem is, that the problem persist on my localhost, so I doubt it's jsFiddle's problem...

Comment: also problem can be in versions. what version you use for jquery and what for jquery.UI?

Comment: Clear cache + cookies, make sure you load in jQuery core + jQuery UI correctly.. Also, use tools like FireBug to follow it thoroughly in your browser. As for [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), don't load jQuery UI as an external resource - hence the problem. Try 1.9.1 with jQuery UI 1.9.2 for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the versions of jQuery and jQuery UI.

as of jQuery version 1.9 the browser() method has been removed. You can use different/older versions of the libraries to fix the problem.

```
The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMgx8/6/)

Or perhaps if you don't wish to use an older version of the plugin, use [**jQuery Migrate plugin**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/).

Comment: I am using jquery UI v 1.11.0 and jQuery v 1.11.1, does this mean I cant use jquery 1.edge to get resizable() working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include another version of jQueryUI in your code.  [This version](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js) shuld work.